# Dynamic Tag for a WooComerce Affiliate Product (WordPress + Elementor Pro)

Tags: php, woocommerce, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

So I have an issue with WooComerce, WordPress, and Elementors Dynamic Tag function.

I have tried working with the "Hello Elementor" theme to customize and add a custom Dynamic Tag under the WooComerce category that will include the "Affiliate Product" from WooComerce's "Product URL" that is a default field that is available but not as a Dynamic Tag sadly.

So where am I trying to add this Dynamic Tag? - Well, there is a Loop Item called "product loop item #1" which I try on the first/top container that contains everything, add a link under "Additional Options" as a Dynamic Tag for the "Product URL" from WooComerce "Affiliate Product".

I have tried making it possible by editing "functions.php" under the Hello Elementor child-theme folder and by creating a new .PHP file under the same location as the "functions.php" called by the name "custom-product-url-tag.php".

Here is the code I use but still doesn't seem to solve my issue due to it's still not showing as an Dynamic Tag option for the containers "Additional Options" for the Link option.

functions.php code:

```
// Retrieve Product URL Shortcode
function retrieve_product_url_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts);

    if (empty($atts['id'])) {
        return '';
    }

    $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    if ($product && $product->is_type('external')) {
        $url = $product->get_product_url();

        if ($url) {
            return esc_url($url);
        }
    }

    return '';
}
add_shortcode('retrieve_product_url', 'retrieve_product_url_shortcode');
```

custom-product-url-tag.php code:

```
<?php
use Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Tag;

class Custom_Product_URL_Tag extends Tag {

    /**
     * Retrieve the dynamic tag title.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_title() {
        return 'Custom Product URL';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the dynamic tag name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom-product-url';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the dynamic tag group.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_group() {
        return 'woocommerce';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the dynamic tag categories.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'woocommerce' ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the dynamic tag value.
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get_value(array $options = []) {
        global $product;

        if ($product && $product->is_type('external')) {
            $url = $product->get_product_url();

            if ($url) {
                return esc_url($url);
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Please let me know what the issue is, thank you.

I tried to create my custom Dynamic Tag, that could be used for the Elementor elementor "Container" where you can can under additional options add "Custom Product URL" as an option, and once select it will take the information from a WooComerce product that is verified as an "Affiliate Product" called "Product URL" and use that field as an input for the Link "Additional Option" for the Container Element as an working Dynamic Group.

Remember this is an Looping Item, so it must be able to retrieve the information also what product it is supposed to take the Product URL from for every individual product.